# cursor.fetchone() returns a value that isn't in the database

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running a stored procedure, from Python, that executes a SELECT query on a MYSQL database to determine whether a record already exists or not.

After this has executed, I use cursor.fetchone() to compare the result of the query with the value of a variable. However, when I inspect the value held in the query result, it is the same as the parameter I passed in with the query even though that record doesn't exist in the database.

Surely this should be `None`?

For the record, the parameter I'm passing has a direction of IN and is an int.

I've checked the rest of SO and all the problems like this that I've seen are the reverse of what I'm getting! I've also researched cursor.fetchone() to make sure I was using it right and it seems I am.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**the table I'm querying**

ID = 1

Name = name

**stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `storedprocedure2`(IN `param` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER

SELECT `This` 
FROM `That` 
WHERE `This` = param
```

**query call**

```
def loadintodatabase(self, connection, args):

    value1 = args[0]
    value2 = args[1]
    value3 = args[2]
    value4 = args[3]
    value5 = args[4]
    value6 = args[5]
    value7 = args[6]
    value8 = args[7] #this is a list
    value8length = len(value8)
    value9 = args[8] #this is also a list
    value9length = len(value9)
    id = 0
    i = 0
    idlist = [] #this is not related to the id variable
    idlistincrement = 0

    if value 8 != []:
        while i < value8length:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('storedprocedure1', (value8[0], value8[1], value8[2])) #Inserts into a different table
            idlist.append(value8[0])
            cursor.close()
            connection.commit()
            i += 1

    i = 0
    if value3 != 0 and value4 is not None:            
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         cursor.callproc('storedprocedure2', (param,)) #lets say param holds 11 as an int, sproc is a select query
         result = cursor.fetchone() #result should be None but instead is (11L,)
         if result is None:
              id = None
         else:
             id = result[0]
         if id is None:
             cursor = connection.cursor()
             cursor.callproc('storedprocedure3', (value3, value4)) #sproc inserts into the table I just selected the id from
             cursor.close()
             connection.commit()
```

Comment: I can see backquotes instead of quotes in the stored procedure. Are they a simple typeo ?

Comment: No? I'm using phpmyadmin to view my database and it marks columns,  tables and databases in backticks

Comment: Please show your complete *python* code, as that will likely hold the answer. Please show the entire stored procedure definition as well.   Is there a reason you even need a stored procedure in this simple case?  Why not just: query='SELECT ID from Table where ID=%s' and curse.execute(query, (param,))?

Comment: Made the edits to include the create procedure function and the rest of the method i'm calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure was slightly wrong.

```
SELECT `This` 
FROM `That` 
WHERE `This` = param
```

should have been

```
BEGIN
SELECT `This` 
FROM `That` 
WHERE `This` = param;
END
```

Now cursor.fetchone() returns `None` as expected!